# How do I extract fingerprints from .ssh/known_hosts? but filtering for a specific key type

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keygen, fingerprint

I read this question:

- [How do I extract fingerprints from .ssh/known_hosts?](https://superuser.com/questions/529132/how-do-i-extract-fingerprints-from-ssh-known-hosts)

The answer is valid, so I tried some variations:

```
ssh-keygen           -lf   ~/.ssh/known_hosts -F 192.168.1.X
ssh-keygen           -lvf  ~/.ssh/known_hosts -F 192.168.1.X
ssh-keygen -E md5    -lvf  ~/.ssh/known_hosts -F 192.168.1.X
ssh-keygen -E sha256 -lvf  ~/.ssh/known_hosts -F 192.168.1.X
```

All work as expected.

How an observation: for any command share above, it shows all the *fingerprint* together based in their own *key types*, such as `rsa`, `ecdsa` etc .... I am ok with this, but ... the reason of this post

**Question:**

- How to execute the `ssh-keygen` command with a filter for a specific `key type`?

Something similar as the `ssh-keyscan` has with the `-t` option, therefore something like:

```
ssh-keygen -lf   ~/.ssh/known_hosts -F 192.168.1.X -? rsa
ssh-keygen -lf   ~/.ssh/known_hosts -F 192.168.1.X -? ecdsa
```

So what could be `?`? - I saw the `ssh-keygen --help` and seems there is no that support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Korn-like shells, you could always do:

```
ssh-keygen -lf <(grep ' ssh-rsa ' ~/.ssh/known_hosts) -F localhost
```

Same with fish:

```
ssh-keygen -lf (grep ' ssh-rsa ' ~/.ssh/known_hosts|psub) -F localhost
```

Or other shells assuming a system that has `/dev/stdin` (most these days):

```
grep ' ssh-rsa ' ~/.ssh/known_hosts | ssh-keygen -lf /dev/stdin -F localhost
```

That assumes `ssh-rsa` is not found anywhere else on the lines of those `known_hosts` files (like in comments or options).

Comment: Thanks, interesting, there is no an own `ssh-keygen`'s option that offers this. I assumed perhaps I understood in a wrong way some option shown through `--help`. Let me test your answer and it is going to be marked as valid